# How to only display the first two plots of `plot(model)` in script mode?

Tags: r, plot, user-interaction

I have a script that essentially boils down to

```
model <- lm(d$o ~ d$t * d$w)
plot(model)
```

When I run these commands in interactive mode (RStudio), `plot` will create four graphs. The user has to advance to the next graph by pressing enter.

Now, I want to run the commands in (almost) non-interactive mode and the `plot` command to display only the first two graphs. The user of the script of course should still be required to mouse click or press enter *after* the R environment has displayed the first and second graph.

How could I achieve this?

### Edit

It has been suggested that I use the `which` parameter (being described in `?plot.lm`). Yet, if I change the respective line to

```
plot(model, which=1)
```

the script aborts with

```
Error in box(...) : invalid 'which' argument
Calls: plot -> plot.default -> localBox -> box
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "which" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "which" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "which" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "which" is not a graphical parameter
Execution halted
```

Comment: Probably `which` argument of `plot`.

Comment: ...as described in the very first sentence in the help text: "Six plots (selectable by `which`)".

Comment: Yes, right, that is in `?plot.lm` of which I was hitherto unaware. Thanks for pointing me to this direction.

Comment: Do you get the error if you run the command interactively? Alternatively, you could plot things "manually" yourself. For example, the residual plot can be done by `plot(model$fitted.values, model$residuals, xlab = "Fitted Values", ylab = "Residuals", type = "n"); panel.smooth(model$fitted.values, model$residuals, col = "red"); points(model$fitted.values, model$residuals); abline(h = 0, lty = 3, col = "grey")
`. Look at `str(model)` for all the elements in the `lm` object and `getAnywhere(plot.lm)` to see how the function is doing each plot. (not very straighforward, but might get you there...)

Comment: Your `plot` call dispatches to `plot.default`, whereas it should to `plot.lm`. Probably your `model` object is not of class `lm` somehow. Try `plot.lm` directly?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
plot(model, which=1:2).
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know your data. But this works!

```
n=50
d=data.frame(o=rnorm(n,10,3),t=1:n,w=rep(c("A","B","C"),length.out=n))
model <- lm(d$o ~ d$t * d$w)
plot(model)
op=par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:4)plot(model, which=i)
par(op)
```

[image]